# Decode binary file in AWS environment using PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, binaryfiles, netezza

Is it possible to consume a Netezza backup file in AWS environment and load it to Redshift.
File is a compressed binary file created using the below query. This file can also be produced using NZ_BACKUP utility in Netezza for a full database.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'C:\filename.bak' USING (remotesource 'ODBC' FORMAT 'internal' 
COMPRESS true) AS SELECT * FROM schema.tablename;

or 

nzbackup -dir /home/user/backups -u user -pw password -db db1
```

I want this file to be decoded and load to a data frame in AWS environment utilizing Python or PySpark (glue). Following are the steps I am planning to do in AWS. I need some guidance in the first step. How to decode a compressed binary from Netezza.

1. Decode the file to ASCII (How?)
2. Load to DF and generate parquet
3. Copy to Redshift